# ROUTING key found for default - this is no longer needed in Channels 2

Tags: django, websocket, routes, channel

I want to integrate Django Channels.I have installed all required dependencies,and while starting the app server starts listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000. My routing is specified as follows:

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/chat/(?P<room_name>[^/]+)/$', consumer.ChannelConsumer),
]
```

And the Consumer file:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json

class ChannelConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        # self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        # self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        # 
        # # Join room group
        # await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        #     self.room_group_name,
        #     self.channel_name
        # )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

However I cant open connection. Handshake fails

Comment: Did you configure your settings.py file?

Comment: Thanks, i fixed it. I forgot some additional settings from previos version. I commented them and everything worked.

Comment: what settings did you forgot? I got same error here....and Im upgrading too.

Answer (score 11):

Delete **ROUTING** on **CHANNEL_LAYERS** settings

And change **BACKEND** to **channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer**

Example:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [('localhost','6379')],
        },
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
    },
}
```

This happens just if you are upgrading channels 1.X to 2